# Equality of two expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the following true for even integer n = 2m > 1?

$\sum_{k=1}^m 2^{2k-1} 
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
n \\
2k-1 \\
\end{array}} \right)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m 2^{2k} 
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
n \\
2k \\
\end{array}} \right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace n by 2m on both sides. 
Now we have to prove -
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}2^{2k-1}{2m \choose 2k-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}2^{2k}{2m \choose 2k}
$$

Now consider the following two equations -

$$
(x + 1)^{2m} = {2m \choose 0}x^0 + {2m \choose 1}x^1 + {2m \choose 2}x^2 + ... + {2m \choose 0}x^{2m -1} + {2m \choose 2m}x^{2m}
$$

$$
(x - 1)^{2m} = {2m \choose 0}x^0 - {2m \choose 1}x^1 + {2m \choose 2}x^2 - ... - {2m \choose 0}x^{2m -1} + {2m \choose 2m}x^{2m}
$$

Adding them we have -

$$
\frac{(x - 1)^{2m} + (x + 1)^{2m}}{2} = {2m \choose 0}x^0 + {2m \choose 2}x^2 + ...  + {2m \choose 2m}x^{2m} = {2m \choose 0}x^0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}x^{2k}{2m \choose 2k}
$$

Subtracting them we have -

$$
\frac{(x + 1)^{2m} - (x + 1)^{2m}}{2} = {2m \choose 1}x^1 + {2m \choose 3}x^3 + ...  + {2m-1 \choose 2m}x^{2m-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}x^{2k-1}{2m \choose 2k-1}
$$

Now in the 2 equations just derived substitute x = 2. This results in -

$$
\frac{(2-1)^{2m} + (2+1)^{2m}}{2} = {2m \choose 0} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}2^{2k}{2m \choose 2k} =: (a)
$$

$$
\frac{(2+1)^{2m} - (2-1)^{2m}}{2} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}2^{2k-1}{2m \choose 2k-1} =:(b)
$$

Now manipulating (a) we have -
$$
\frac{3^{2m} - 1}{2} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}2^{2k}{2m \choose 2k}
$$
This is equal to the the left hand side of (b).

Hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

Write this as RHS - LHS:
\begin{align}
\sum_{1 \le k \le m} \binom{2 m}{2 k} 2^{2 k}
  - \sum_{1 \le k \le m} \binom{2 m}{2 k - 1} 2^{2 k - 1}
  &= \sum_{1 \le k \le m} \binom{2 m}{2 k} (-1)^{2 k} 2^{2 k}
       + \sum_{1 \le k \le m} \binom{2 m}{2 k - 1} (-1)^{2 k - 1} 2^{2 k - 1} \\
  &= \sum_{0 \le r \le 2 m} \binom{2 m}{r} (-1)^r 2^r - 1 \\
  &= (1 - 2)^{2 m} - 1 \\
  &= 0
\end{align}